# VUEJS List items editable with button @click (button is in another component)

Tags: vuejs2, click, vue-component, parent-child, v-for

I need to make list items editable on click.
I have a template with a card displaying the list items, and a button component that contains, among others, a button that will trigger modify(). When this button is clicked the list items should become text inputs and a save button should appear at the bottom.

I read about contentEditable = true, but I don't know where to set it. If it's @click, the button component needs to be aware of the list items. 
How to let the button know about those list items?
`<button />` should be child of `<detailActivity>`... so **Props?**

Here's the template with the list items: `<detailActivity />`

```
<b-row>
<b-card
  header-tag="header"
  footer-tag="footer"
  class="text-center"
>
  <h3 slot="header" class="mb-0">Activity Details</h3>
  <ul
    v-for="value in currentActivity"
    :key="value.id"
    class="listValues">
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
  </ul>
  <div slot="footer">
    <buttons />
  </div>
</b-card>  
</b-col> 
<b-col xs="8">
<activity-map />   
</b-col>
</b-row>
```

Inside the `<button />` component, among others, the edit button:

```
<b-button 
  variant="warning" 
  @click="edit"
>
```

Any idea on how I should do this?

THANKS

Comment: What I understood from your problem description here is that you want a view form, which can be editable once user clicks on a button. If that is so then I think this [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) would be useful. Show editable form when user clicks on edit button, i.e. change flag of form in the function. As Vue is reactive in nature, it will show the form for that particular row. Would be more clear if you can share complete code for this component.

Comment: There's no much more code to show, as I am not sure on how to proceed. More than plain code infact, I was looking for a reasoning about how to deal with it. I have a series of list item rendered through v-for (I posted this part of code). Is it possible to 'transform' them in text input when @click? Well, I know it is (contentEditable true the simplest way), I was more concerned on how to do it, as the button that triggers this action is in another component.